# How do I get data from Mongodb to display in Fullcalendar while using meteor.js

Tags: mongodb, meteor, fullcalendar

I am trying to use Fullcalendar with Meteor.js.  It seems that Fullcalendar can use JSON for its events.  Like this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
events: [
    {
        title  : 'event1',
        start  : '2013-06-01'
    },
    {
        title  : 'event2',
        start  : '2013-06-05',
        end    : '2013-06-07'
    },
    {
        title  : 'event3',
        start  : '2013-06-09 12:30:00',
        allDay : false // will make the time show
    }
]
```

});

I am trying to store this data in a Mongodb and then output the data to the full calendar.

I am not sure how to make this happen and would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hi rjsandman try search stack for fullcalendar ajax call and JSON call, Load events with does tecnologys and refer to the Fullcalendar documentation. I'm sure you can figure it out.

To output your data depending on your server side tecnology you have to send back to your client side like a String or well formed XML with your already formatted events.

This is an example on how you can send the events back:

XML format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <root>
    <events>
     <event title="Mytitle" start="20-03-2014 10:30:00" end="20-03-2014 12:30:00" allDay=false></event>
     and so on...
    </events>
  </root>
```

JSON format:

```
[
   {"title":"Mytitle","start":"20-03-2014 10:30:00","end":"20-03-2014 12:30:00" "allDay":false},
   {"title":"Mytitle","start":"20-03-2014 10:30:00","end":"20-03-2014 12:30:00" "allDay":false},
   {"title":"Mytitle","start":"20-03-2014 10:30:00","end":"20-03-2014 12:30:00" "allDay":false}
]
```

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I was trying to get data from a Mongodb.  Would I need t do something like Db.find(); added somewhere in the full calendar call?  I didn't see anything for Mongo on the fullcalendar website.

Comment: You have to think that Fullcalendar its just a server side API with limited methods regarding to the calendar only. You just have to feed it with does formats. There is no method to fetch data directly from any type of Database. That is something you have to create yourself. I see the mongoDB returns already JSON, but the method to fetch the data you have to make it. 

Hope i clarified you enought.

Comment: So couldn't I get the data from the Mongodb and hold it in a variable and then use the variable in the Full Calendar Call?

Comment: Yes that's what i am trying to tell you :P but fullcalendar doesnt have any method to do that you have to make it. Btw "Fullcalendar its just a server side API " i meant client side, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Event Data function to generate Event Objects.

Assuming that you have a template named `events` :

#### ./events.js

```js
import { Events } from './path/to/your/mongo/collection';

Template.events.onRendered( () => {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        events: (start, end, timezone, callback) => {
            let data = Events.find().fetch().map(() => {
                return event; //data is now an array with JSON format
            });

            if (data) {
                callback(data);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

More info [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/).